# Xcode Simulator keyboard slow to respond

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am getting this error in my debug window when using the keyboard in simulator mode.

```
-[UIKeyboardInputManagerClient handleError:forRequest:] will retry sending handleKeyboardInput:keyboardState:completionHandler: to keyboard daemon after receiving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.TextInput" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.TextInput}
```

Text entry freezes, catches up and then freezes again when entering using the keyboard. I seems to be trying to connect to a service. Turning the Wifi off the problem goes away.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?